# How to generate release hash key in SMS retriever API for auto detecting OTP?

Tags: android

I generated 11 character code for SMS retriever. Its working in debug mode but in release mode its not working. How to generate release hash key in windows ?

Comment: https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/autofill-otp-verification-with-latest-sms-retriever-api-73c788636783 please refer

Comment: I tried by referring this. It worked in debug mode but when I updated my app in play store, it did not work. I used AppSignatureHelper  class to generate the hash key but it was a debug key.

Comment: then try this https://prishanmaduka.medium.com/generate-hash-keys-properly-for-android-sms-retriever-api-c26b9be42ddc